# "Error looking up a data source : null" in appserver 4.1.2 of wso2

Tags: wso2

I downloaded the appserver 4.1.2 (latest) from the wso2 site. Unfortunately when I tried to add a datasource I got an error message ("Error looking up a data source : null").

I found only one solution in the forum to update something. However when I add those repositories I cant find an update for the datasource component. I have to confess that I am a newbie and maybe I did something wrong.

Any more detailed help would be nice because without the datasource feature the appserver is worthless for me. I wonder how this work in production environments.

Thx,

Juergen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be a know issue. Can you try WSO2 DSS 2.6.3. you can download it from here[1].

[1] http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server

Comment: Ya, but I need to use the application server not the data-service-server because i need to deploy webapps for example. As I told I am a newbie to wso2 and I thought I cant run both the appserver and the dataserver. And I cant find an update for the appserver which solve this problem.

Comment: in that case you can do other way round. i.e install web application and service hosting features to Data services server. Follow these steps. First go to features and go to Repository Management. Add a new repository. Repository location is http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/3.2.2. Now go to available features and search features. Install select following features and install them. web app management
web app application management
web app application deployment
service hosting .